Can I simultaneously refactor method argument lists in a defining interface and its implementing classes' methods, in Visual Studio (C#)?
I have an interface:
interface ISomeThing{

  void SomeMethod(string arg1);

}

And I have an implementation:
class SomeThing: ISomeThing{

  void SomeMethod(string arg1){

      //some method code here blah 

  }

}

Using VS2022, if I right click the impl method and choose "Go To Definition" I am transported to the interface.
If I right click the interface spec for the method and choose "Go To Implementation", I am transported to the impl method.
This makes nav quite easy...
But when I want to add another argument:
SomeMethod(string arg1, int arg2);

whichever one I change first, I then lose the ability to navigate to the other one via the relevant "Go To ..."
To work around this I tend to drag the interface into a floating window, Go To the impl and then I have the two windows side by side, and I can make the same code change twice..
..but is there a way that I can just add the new argument to interface, or the class, the other is updated automagically and the Go To still work?
There is a refactor option to change the signature and update referencing sites, but that UI is very clunky compared to just typing e.g. , int arg2..
I could change the impl and then pull up, but I'm still left with having to replace the old definition with the new one, coalescing the two down to one
I'd like to know if is there a way that is similar to the way Ctrl-RR ("rename" a member) works, that can alter the argument list in multiple places, from either the interface or an implementing class such that the same edit is made in the other place(s)..

Change the interface then go to the implementing class click on the interface there and hit "implement interface" in the context menu.

But that adds an empty method void SomeMethod(string x, int y) { throw new NotImp... }, rather than upgrading the existing method to have the with the new parameter? I then need to cut that new method's signature, find the old method, and paste the signature over the top, right?

For example yes. What you want feels complicated. Changing the signature does not change the implementation so you want t have a refactoring that creates broken code at first. And if you do everything at the same time at some point it hard to distinguish between i wanted a new method or i wanted to replace the method with something that looks completely different (and is broken at first). Would be a case for an AI as refactoring that learns from your personal behavior and your typical refactoring and coding style.

I don't see it as complicated, and "Change signature" can do it, but it's painful, naturally, as it asks a lot of questions like "and what do you want to do at all the call sites?". This use case is where there is an interface, an impl and a test, and I need another argument. I'm happy that it breaks because the compiler then helps me jump around; I'd like to "Ctrl-RR" the interface or impl and add the argument (probably better on the interface and have all the impl's update), and all the calls/tests break("call does not have the right number of arguments") - I can jump to those from the error

What I cannot do, if i change either the interface or the/an impl is easily jump to the other place, because it's severed the interface:impl link; suddenly the impl doesn't implement the interface any more, but there isn't a "X doesn't implement IX.SomeMethod and the best match X.SomeMethod has the wrong number of arguments"... It's just "X doesn't implement IX.SomeMethod", with no easy way to jump from where I am (IX.SomeMethod) to where i want to edit (X.SomeMethod)... Hence I ask if there is some way I don't know about to make both edits simultaneously. Perhaps Find/Replace is the way..

Use Resharper change signature:

Or Apply change signature refactoring
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Refactorings__Change_Signature.html#performing-the-refactoring-in-place

I cast around for feedback from the team and had the following suggestion mooted:
If we open the CodeLens #References pop, it contains a small icon in the top right that will convert the popup to a floating/dockable tool panel:

Usefully, the contents of this window is like a Find Results; it doesn't refresh even if you change the code, so one can pop it, change the interface then use the listed set of references (now out of date, technically) to jump around the code to all the other locations that a method referenced the interface, making the same change to the signature.
It's not exactly a "one place change all" that the question requests, but it's close, because it etablishes a single panel that contains all the places references are made, and it's a workaround for the pain point presented the question that changing the singtaure of e.g. the interface loses the ability to easily navigate to the implementations.
Fixing up the implementation signatures using an entire line copy paste is fairly trivial once the nav problem is solved
